# arangodb truncate fails on large a collection

Tags: arangodb

I get a timeout in arangosh and the arangodb service gets unresponsive if I try to truncate a large collection of ~40 million docs. Message:

```
arangosh [database_xxx]> db.[collection_yyy].truncate() ; JavaScript exception in file '/usr/share/arangodb/js/client/modules/org/arangodb/arangosh.js' at 104,13: [ArangoError 2001: Error reading from: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'timeout during read'] !
  throw new ArangoError(requestResult); !  ^ stacktrace: Error
    at Object.exports.checkRequestResult (/usr/share/arangodb/js/client/modules/org/arangodb/arangosh.js:104:13)
    at ArangoCollection.truncate (/usr/share/arangodb/js/client/modules/org/arangodb/arango-collection.js:468:12)
    at <shell command>:1:11
```

`ArangoDB 2.6.9` on `Debian Jessie`, `AWS ec2 m4.xlarge`, 16G RAM, SSD.
The service gets unresponsive. I suspect it got stuck (not just busy), because it doesn't work until after I stop, delete database in /var/lib/arangodb/databases/, then start again.

I know I may be leaning towards the limits of performance due to the size, but I would guess that it is the intention not to fail regardless of size.

However on a non cloud Windows 10, 16GB RAM, SSD the same action succeeded well - after a while.

Is it a bug? I have some python code that loads dummy data into a collection if it helps. Please let me know if I shall provide more info.
Would it help to fiddle with -`-server.request-timeout` ?

Comment: An update. Referring to the tests in my initial post.
I repeated the truncate action on AWS ec2 m4.xlarge, but this time on ArangoDB version 2.7.0. The action succeeded correctly without going into a dead state. Something got fixed :-)
It still took a longer than inserting the same data though. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing `--server.request-timeout` for the ArangoShell will only increase the timeout that the shell will use before it closes an idle connection. 
The arangod server will also shut down lingering keep-alive connections, and that may happen earlier. This is controlled via the server's `--server.keep-alive-timeout` setting.

However, increasing both won't help much. The actual problem seems to be the `truncate()` operation itself. And yes, it may be very expensive. `truncate()` is a transactional operation, so it will write a deletion marker for each document it removes into the server's write-ahead log. It will also buffer each deletion in memory so the operation can be rolled back if it fails.

A much less intrusive operation than `truncate()` is to instead drop the collection and re-create it. This should be very fast. 
However, indexes and special settings of the collection need to be recreated / restored manually if they existed before dropping it.

For a document collection, it can be achieved like this:

```
function dropAndRecreateCollection (collectionName) {
  // save state
  var c          = db._collection(collectionName);
  var properties = c.properties();
  var type       = c.type();
  var indexes    = c.getIndexes();

  // drop existing collection
  db._drop(collectionName);

  // restore collection
  var i;
  if (type == 2) {
      // document collection
      c = db._create(collectionName, properties);
      i = 1;
  }
  else {
      // edge collection
      c = db._createEdgeCollection(collectionName, properties);
      i = 2;
  }

  // restore indexes
  for (; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
      c.ensureIndex(indexes[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer and a useful script! The drop workaround suits me fine since all configuration and loading is going to scripted anyway. If I were in arangodb dev, I would still investigate it further since one installation does the job within 30 minutes and another is still down the day after. Both SSD, 16GB RAM and the same data set.